# How do I allow a user to guess the entire word in my Hangman application?

Tags: java

I have a hangman game, and it runs perfectly except that I can't figure out how to allow the user to guess the entire word if they want to, instead of just an individual letter every time. How do I do that?

```java
public class HangmanHelper {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String play; // 'y' or 'n'
        int missed = 0;
        do {
            // Generate a random word 
            char[] word = getWord();

            // Display each letter in the word as an asterisk.
            char[] asterisks = new char[word.length];
            fillAsterisks(asterisks);
            do {
                // Prompt the user to guess one letter
                char guess = getGuess(asterisks);       

                // Check if is letter is correct
                if (!isCorrectGuess(word, asterisks, guess)) {
                                   missed++;

                                   if (missed == 6) {
                                       System.out.printf("Sorry, you've exceeded the max number of incorrect guesses!%n");
                                       System.exit(0);
                                   }
                                }


            } while (!isWordFinish(asterisks));

            // Print results
            print(word, missed);

            // Ask the user whether to continue to play with another word
            System.out.println("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n>");
            play = input.next();

        } while (play.charAt(0) == 'y');
    }

    /* getWord randomly generates a word from a file */
    public static char[] getWord() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Create File object
        File file = openFile();

        // Create an ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
            // Create input file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
                        ){
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                words.add(input.next());
            }
        }

        // Pick a random string
        String pick = words.get((int)(Math.random() * words.size()));

        // Convert string to character array
        char[] word = pick.toCharArray();

        return word;
    }

    /** Return File object */
    public static File openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("hangman.txt");

        // Check if file exists
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.print("File " + file.getName() + " does not exist");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return file;
    }

    /** fillAsterisks initializes a list with asterisks */
    public static void fillAsterisks(char[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = '*';
        }
    }

    /** checkGuess tests if the users guess was correct */
    public static boolean isCorrectGuess(char[] word, char[] blanks, char guess) {
        boolean correct = false;
        int message = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (word[i] == guess) {
                correct = true;
                if (blanks[i] == guess)
                    message = 1;
                else { 
                    blanks[i] = guess; // the actual letter is then displayed.
                    message = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (message > 0)
            print(message, guess);
        return correct;
    }

    /** isWordFinish */
    public static boolean isWordFinish(char[] blanks) {
        for (char e: blanks) {
            if (e == '*')
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** print overloaded */
    public static void print(char[] word, int missed) {
        System.out.print("The word is ");
        System.out.print(word);
        System.out.println(" You missed " + missed + 
            (missed > 1 ? " times" : " time"));
    }

    /** print overloaded */
    public static void print(int m, char guess) {
        System.out.print("\t" + guess);
        switch (m) {
            case 1 : System.out.println(" is already in the word"); break;
            case 2 : System.out.println(" is not in the word");
        }
    }

    /** getGuess prompts the user to guess one letter at a time */
    public static char getGuess(char[] asterisks){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");
        System.out.print(asterisks);
        System.out.print(" > ");
        String g = input.next();
        return g.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `getGuess` could return a `String`, you could then use `String#length` to determine if the user enter one or more characters and take appropriate action from there

Answer (score 3):

You could just choose an arbitrary phrase or input that is not related to any of the possible solutions. For example, in your getGuess() method you could do:

```
public static char getGuess(char[] asterisks){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");
    System.out.print(asterisks);
    System.out.print(" > ");
    String g = input.next();
    if (g.equals("I want to guess!"){
        // handle the guess here
    } else {
        return g.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

There are really endless ways to go about implementing such a solution and this is one of them.

Comment: I was going to write one which assign the guess to the special char '!' but yours is also good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
Where: Word is a string and is the input
   "HangmanWord" Is the string required for input

```
if(word.equals("HangmanWord") return true;
else return false;
```

That could be a different method, and it checks that first, then has an else statement should my method return false.